# How to get value of second column, that is the same name with another column in dataTable by C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I have a dataTable get from calling a stored procedure in SQL Server, it has 2 columns with the same name: NAME_PROJECT

Example: result from this query:

```
SELECT
    NAME_PROJECT,
    DATE,
    ...
    NAME_PROJECT,
    ...
FROM
    TABLE_A
```

This is my code in C#, it always get value of the first column:

```
dataTable.Rows[i].Field<string>("NAME_PROJECT")
```

Because some reason, I can not change KEY "NAME_PROJECT" from SQL to avoid the same name column.

How to get value of the second NAME_PROJECT column in this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide us with a bit more information. Possibly the stored procedure in question? Any SQL errors you get trying to change? I am quite curious why it is you can't resolve this issue on the database side rather than fight a poorly designed DB on the client side

Comment: Because this store procedure was used at another functions. Now, I'm creating new output data function that will invoke this store procedure and get values.
Therefore, I can not edit this store procedure, I can only customize on C#.
Do you have another solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301394(v=vs.110).aspx) is overloaded to accept column index as well, you could use pass an index in this case.

```
dataTable.Rows[i].Field<string>(2);
```

**Update:**

Since you want to take second column when there are duplicate column names, I would suggest doing this.

```
var column = dataTable.Columns
                      .OfType<DataColumn>()
                      .LastOrDefault(x=> x.ColumnName == "columnname");

if(column != null)
{
     dataTable.Rows[i].Field<string>(column); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, 
but this store procedure have over 100 columns, and it is not fixed, output columns was control by environment paramters that can set enable or disable display columns. Based on index column will difficult to avoid error in the future. Do you have a another solution?

Comment: Hmm... tough situation, is this the case you want to take second column when there are duplicates?

Comment: >you want to take second column when there are duplicates?
yes, T_T

Comment: Thanks, I tried your updated answer. But it also get the first column.

Comment: Strange, I suggest debug the solution and see what is exactly happening.

Comment: I checked and debug.
When I execute store procedure at SQL Server 2012, It returned columns the same name.
When I debug in C# (Visual Studio 2012), I see that the second column,  C# changed name: "NAME_PROJECT" to become "NAME_PROJECT1"
I think that seem C# did not allow return dataTable that has columns the same name.
Now, I can get value second column with name: "NAME_PROJECT1"
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could alias one of the duplicate column names in your query so that the result set returned by the stored procedure doesn't have the duplicate column name problem

Comment: OP mentioned _Because some reason, I can not change KEY "NAME_PROJECT _

Comment: @HariPrasad An alias is not a change

Comment: I suspect what he meant "he cannot change on db side"

Comment: @HariPrasad I figured he wasn't able to make a change due to foreign key dependencies. There really needs to be more info provided

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use Index for selecting the column you need.

```
string Second_Name_Porject = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[2];
```